# Appendix at the final and with a modified title

Tags: appendices, appendix

I've looking for a way to add the appendix at the final of my article, and found a way to do so with the command `\appendixpage` but when I compile the code the output shows a title **Appendices**, which is in english, but the article is in spanish so I expect to translate that title to spanish, how can I change it? I'll let a sample code of what I've done below and an image of what I get as an output.

```
\begin{document}

\section{Section1}
A bunch of text

\section{Section2}
A bunch of text

\appendix
\appendixpage
\section{Appendix page}
Appendix text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`). Where does `\appendixpage` come from? How do you set the article in Spanish? At a guess, try `\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{<Spanish Appendices>}`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Peter, and sorry for the lack of a complete MWE. Fortunately what've suggested was enough and I could format the title as I wish!